# Android - NullPointerException while setting custom toolbar in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to set a custom image into my title bar.

Running the below code returns the following:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.me.project/com.me.project.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setTitle(int)' on a null object reference
```

`toolbar` is null. Why? `R.id.app_toolbar` is not null here.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.app_toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.app_icon);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new HomeScreenFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/app_toolbar"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**app_toolbar.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/app_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156468/nullpointerexception-while-setting-toolbar) and was not able to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` into `onCreate()`

Comment: did so, now I am getting `This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.` traced back to `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

Comment: Update your styles.xml.  Need to use <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"> into activity theme

Comment: thanks, that solved the error. now the custom toolbar is displaying as a background however. that's another issue anyway

Answer (score 2):

Change theme to NoActionBar first then use custom toolbar

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```